# Side by side figures from tex input

Tags: subfloats, input

I have some plots obtained through gnuplot with epslatex terminal. The output is in two files for each plot: (1) foo.eps and (2) foo.tex.

I want to put these plots side by side in a tex document. But with subfigure or minipage I got some problems...

I want to do something like this

```
\documentclass{toptesi}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\input{foo1.tex}
\caption{bla bla}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\input{foo2.tex}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but the images are not rescaled according to the subfigure width, even though caption is. How to do that?

Comment: I would insert the `.eps` files or set the tex-code in a minipage into the subfigure. (haven't tried that). If this does not work, we need to see such a picture I guess.

Comment: I couldn't put the eps because the eps output of gnuplot doesn't contain the labels that are in the tex file (this because epslatex works in this way). The minipage seems to have the same problem of subfigure...

Comment: Well then I fear we will need such a `.tex` file. I have no idea what is inside of it. But the subfigure will need some info like bounding boxes in order to scale it. Just export some simple graph from gnuplot and add it to your post.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that I tried and it works. I have put the \input inside a resizebox like this

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{foo.tex}}
```

where \textwidth is half a page width because is inside subfigure environment.

I don't know if there are better solutions but this works...

Edit:

The only problem is with the labels that - I don't know why - are out of the borders and is needed to adjust manually the sizes of subfigures and the hspace between them... Still searching for better solutions... :-)

Comment: The `0.5\textwidth` is giving you the problem with spaces. It is essentially a minipage. Use something like `0.47\textwidth`.